# Set all returned data to textview from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to set the random data from my table to a single textview.I am able to fetch random data from sqlite but I can not set it to my textview.Probably I should not use setText to put it there.
"Generate" function should bring each time random data from that table.

**- main class -**

*I am having my problem down here* (Part of the above class)

```
private void generatecompliment() {
    Cursor cursor = mydb.generatecompliments();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String[] compliments1 = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    //cursor.moveToNext();
    shwtxt.setText(cursor.getString(1));

}}
```

**- databasehelper class-**

```
    public Cursor generatecompliments () {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase2 = getReadableDatabase();
        String sql ="SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME2 + "ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1";
        return sqLiteDatabase2.rawQuery(sql, null);
    } 
}
```

Note:I have a third class which uses another table but I did not put it here since its working fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I would just ask what is the minimal API you have to support and if you have heard of Android Architecture components. They can make a lot of things easier for you.

Comment: Api level 19.And yeah I heard about architecture components but this app is pretty small already.I just have problem with this setting text I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

I believe that you would want something like :-

```
private void generatecompliment() {
    boolean done_first_column = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.generatecompliments();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for (String column_name; cursor.getColumnNames) {
            if (done_first_column) {
                sb.append(" "); //<<<<<<<<<< separator between column data
            }
            sb.append(cursor.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(column_name));
            done_first_column = true;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    shwtxt.setText(sb.toString());   
}
```

or alternatively

```
private void generatecompliment() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.generatecompliments();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i =0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" "); //<<<<<<<<<< separator between column data
            }
            sb.append(cursor.getString(i);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    shwtxt.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

The difference being that the first gets a String array of the column names using the Cursor [**getColumnNames**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnNames()) method, whilst the second retrieves the number of columns retrieved from the Cursor [**getColumnCount**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getColumnCount()) method.

- This assumes that by saying ***all returned data*** that you want data from all columns concatenated.
- This also assumes that you want a space separating the data from each column.
- There is also the assumption that **shwtxt** has been appropriately instantiated.
- The above code is in-principle code, it has not been tested or run so it may caontain some small errors.

Comment: The second code worked just like I wanted.Thanks.By the way I had problem with my random method in my sqlite query I also had to correct it then it started to work smooth.